# CSS3 @Media How to remove

Tags: html, css

i have a question, so I would like to use @media tag, Is it possible to remove IMAGE

```
<img>
```

from the div after web resizing?

I mean something like that

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
#content{
  remove Image from this div content
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

You switch the display property. Standard the image display property is `inline`. To remove it from that particular div you can use:

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
  #content img {
    display:none;
  }
}
```